# caps lock icon for wireless keyboard?

Tags: shortcut-keys, wireless-keyboards

I recently replaced my old wired keyboard with a Logitech model K330 wireless unit.

The keyboard performs perfectly. My only problem is that I am a lousy typist.

Many times when typing an <kbd>A</kbd>, I will accidentally hit the <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd> key.

Is there a mod available that would notify to the user if *caps lock* in enabled?

Something simple like the word "CAPS" in a colored background on the bottom of the screen?
*No, I don't like the cattle prod under the seat notification method. That is much too noisy.*

Comment: I disable the capslock as that happens to me as well, fat fingers. Got to your settings for keyboard and under options you'll see on option to do that

Answer (score 0):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/indicator-keylock-ubuntu 
try this Web site it works on ubuntu 13.10

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For GNOME 3 exists an shell-extension which indicates if CAPS LOCK and NUM LOCK are activated.
It's on the [official extension site](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/36/lock-keys/).